# Do coset representatives of a normal group form a subgroup of G?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let G be a FINITE group and N is a normal subgroup of G .
Let K be a set of representatives of the cosets of N . Is K a subgroup of G ? is there any specific condition for them to form a subgroup of G?

Answer (score 2):

Not in general, no. The existence of a choice of representatives that form a subgroup is exactly the condition for $G$ to be a [semidirect product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product) of $N$ and $G/N$.

The answer is still the same for finite groups. The smallest counterexample is the cyclic group of order 4, $G = \langle \sigma \rangle$ with $\sigma$ order 4, and $N = \langle \sigma^2\rangle$. Then $G/N$ is the cyclic group of order 2, but the coset representatives of the nontrivial element of $G/N$ are $\sigma$ and $\sigma^{-1}$, neither of which has order 2.

Comment: please give me a reference with a proof for this

Comment: Have you seen semidirect products before? It might be a good exercise for you to figure out a proof of this yourself.

Comment: I just wanted you to recommend a book for this topic

Comment: Artin is a good introductory algebra text if that's what you're asking for. I don't have a copy handy to check whether it has this proposition specifically, but it shouldn't be too far off; this characterization of semidirect product is essentially the motivation that is typically given for the definition in the first place.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein One sufficient condition is that $\langle K \rangle \cap N=\{1\}$.

Comment: I know; that's in the wikipedia page, but the op wanted a text.